# Apostrophe difference (Ones' and Two's Complement)

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, programming, saxon-genitive

Why does the place of the apostrophes differ in the following two titles?

- en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement
- en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement

Which one is the correct?

Comment: They are both corrects. Multiple ones and a singular two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grammatically all the following are correct:

- Two's complement = complement of a single 2
- Twos' complement = complement of a number of twos (plural)
- One's complement = complement of a single 1
- Ones' complement = complement of a number of ones (plural)

The Wikipedia articles ([Ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) describe two's complement and ones' complement as two different mathematical operations. Two's complement is related to a single 2 (to the power of another number) while ones' complement is related to a number of 1s so both are correct.

Comment: I got it, the subtrahend (funny name) is subtracted from the minuend that in the 2's case is 2^4 = 10000 and in the 1s' case is many ones 1111 (for 4 bit representation). Thanks!